# For loop csv combination

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Trying to combine two csv files using the following code:

```
df_source1 = pd.read_csv("3_2_conv_perc_1.csv")
df_source2 = pd.read_csv("3_2_conv_perc_{}.csv".format(i))


df_source1[f'column_{i}'] = df_source2[2]
```

no idea why it is coming up with an error, though my hunch would be it having something to do with f'' operator.

I am using python but in OSGeo4W shell, though I don't think that should be a reason for the code to not work.

here's the error which doesn't explain easily what the problem is to me:

```
>>> df_source1[f'column_{i}'] = df_source2[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3652, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 2

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3654, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 2
```

The data for both files looks like the following:

```
             0        1  2
0          500  1299500  0
1         1500  1299500  0
2         2500  1299500  0
3         3500  1299500  0
4         4500  1299500  0
```

And goes on for more than 909000 rows but I don't think this is a memory issue...

Comment: We'd need to see the data to find the problem. Make a [mre] and provide all details as text, [not a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: Is this the data **in** the file or is this what the dfs look like?

Comment: I believe the problem is `df_source2[2]`, which tries to access a column in the dataframe named `2`, but there is no such column.  It's using `2` as the column _name_, not the _index_.

Comment: @wjandrea the data presented is what the dfs look like when called

Comment: @JohnGordon I do not understand how I would prevent 2 being read as name rather than number. it currently seems that that is the problem.

Comment: I believe you would use `.iloc()` to select a column by its numeric index.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [converting column names to integer with read_csv](/q/37243551/4518341)

Comment: @John You *can* use `.iloc[:, 2]` (note the square brackets), but if you look at the data OP added, the column actually is called "2". It seems like OP was expecting `read_csv` to convert it to int, and I found an existing question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the other dataframe to the first one: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

And then drop the unused columns: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

I strongly prefer Polars over Pandas: https://pola.rs/